# When I start Ubuntu it enters tty[1-6] instead of my desktop (How do I get to desktop?)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, x-server, xampp, lamp

When I start Ubuntu it enters `tty[1-6]` instead of my desktop. Normally I could get back to the desktop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> but that doesn't work.

I tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but it fails.
I tried `startx` which started the `x-server` or `x-window` (not sure what it's called) but it just brought up a black screen with my mouse cursor. If I press <kbd>printscreen</kbd>, a dialog box would open up.

This is a fresh install of the latest version. It's dual booting with Windows 7 - but I doubt that matters. Before this happened, I installed lamp-server but realized it wasn't what I wanted. I then installed xampp and uninstalled lamp-server with `sudo tasksel remove lamp-server`. I restarted with `sudo shutdown -r now` because it would not shut down using the graphical interface.

I can't get back to my desktop. Any ideas how I can?

Comment: was this a fresh install of the latest ubuntu or did you upgrade from an earlier version?

Comment: If you know what happened right before it starting doing this, that would also be helpful to know.

Comment: Fresh install of the latest version. Before this happened, I installed lamp-server, xampp then uninstalled lamp-server with "sudo tasksel remove lamp-server". I forgot to add that to the original question. I will edit it in now.

Comment: When you say "it fails," it helps if you can provide a specific error. There are many ways for apt to fail.

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like you might have managed to uninstall your desktop environment.  (Unless Karmic has replaced GDM, which I doubt.)

If you were using GNOME, you probably installed Karmic with the ubuntu-desktop.  You'll want to reinstall that:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

...or possibly

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

That should pull in any missing packages.  Once you've reinstalled, you should be able to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

... and get back to the GDM login screen.

Comment: I did this and it works well, but I was interested in, is it possible that something is still broken in the system? I have no idea what causes the desktop to fail on my system, but I know that I uninstalled the system python so possibly this caused it to malfunction (https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)? I'm just worried that something is still corrupted, even if the system seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

I think I may be experiencing similar issues.

Since I noticed the mouse I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and it was fixed for me.

It's irritating that this happens a lot when I turn my TV off for a while then on.

Answer (score 3):

My solution has been to edit the file `/etc/lxdm/default.conf` 
and set the server section this way

```
[server]
## arg used to start xserver, not fully function
arg=/usr/bin/X -background vt1
```

Comment: On my machine, there is no folder lxdm in the etc folder...

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

- Logged in to `tty1`
- Purged unity-greeter which was the default lightdm greeter for my unity desktop:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-greeter
  ```
- Then I installed lightdm-gtk-greeter:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -y install lightdm-gtk-greeter
  ```
- Restarted Ubuntu
- Logged in to my desktop
- Removed lightdm-gtk-greeter:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm-gtk-greeter
  ```
- Installed unity-greeter:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -y install unity-greeter
  ```
- Then restarted again and it worked

---

***P.S.*** In case you cannot connect to internet to download and install required packages using apt-get, I suggest you manually download it from Ubuntu package archives from a working computer, save it in a usb drive, mount it from tty1, and then use **dpkg** to install it. Please use *Google* to find out how.

If lightdm-gtk-greeter works for you and you are satisfied with it, you can stop there. However in my experience, it uses slightly more memory than unity-greeter and not as aesthetically good looking as well.

Comment: That didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

First, do this

```
which gdm
```

You should get a response like `/usr/bin/gdm`. If you get an empty line, then gdm is not installed. Re-install it.

After confirming it is there, look in `/etc/init.d`

```
ls /etc/init.d | grep gdm
```

You should, once again, get a line confirming that it is there. Since you were apparently able to run `sudo service gdm start`, it definitely *should* be there.

Now, check for `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

From what I read, you may not have this. If you don't, then create the file.

```
sudo cat << . >> /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/gdm
.
```

Now, restart your system and see if gdm automatically starts or not. This is where everything *should* fall into place. However, sometimes things aren't that simple.

If it fails, look in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/init` again, for anything matching "dm"

```
ls /etc/init{,.d} | grep dm$
```

You'll get a list of all files ending in "dm". Among those, you should see `gdm`.

If you see any other files, then create a directory `/etc/init-disabled` (the name is arbitrary) and move the offending filed into that directory. Don't delete them. They might be important for some other service you have.

For example, if you have lxdm hanging around...

```
sudo mkdir /etc/init-disabled
for i in $(find /etc/init{,.d} -name "*lxdm*"); do 
  mv "$i" /etc/init-disabled/
done
```

Then restart your system once again

If all else fails, try starting X directly using the name of the desktop/window manager. Since you're talking about gdm, I assume you're using gnome, and I believe the command to start gnome is `gnome-session`.

```
xinit /usr/bin/gnome-session -- /usr/bin/X :0
```

I personally run my system without a display-manager, and just have my .bashrc start up my session automatically if `$(tty) == /dev/tty1` and `$SHLVL == 1`. So I've had to get quite intimate with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1: See if this works for you:

First, open terminal by: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>**

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

- Solution 2: If the above doesn’t work, try this

First, open terminal by: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

- Solution 3: If none of the above work for you, try this:

None of the above worked for me however, so I upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. All my previous files were preserved.

First, open terminal by: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>**

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: It says: the following packages have unmet dependencies: libeg1-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa

Answer (score -1):

Login, and type:

```
/etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

This should launch Gnome Desktop Manager.

Comment: This didn't work because gdm wasn't there

Answer (score -3):

Try `Control-Alt-Fn-F7` instead of `Control-Alt-F7`

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit?